# How to display multiselect dropdown value on tag input that is in another div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I need to display multiselect dropdown value on tag input and tag input is present into another div

```html
<div class="tag">
<span>javascript</span>
<span class="material-icons">close</span> 
</div>

<div class="tag">
<span>CSS</span>
<span class="material-icons">close</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please describe what you need to achieve more specifically. The basic functionality you want is not possible to make with HTML. Check Multi-select-dropdowns from bootstrap or similar front-end systems.

Answer (score 1):

Solution Here !!!

```js
  $('select').selectpicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



    <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
      <option>Javascript</option>
      <option>CSS</option>
    
    </select>
```

Comment: thanks @Uday this is the most easiest and perfect soluton on stackoverflow.